# Android Studio warns to remove explicit type arguments when calling generic function

Tags: generics, kotlin

Generic function is as below:

```
fun <T> get(key: String): T? {
        var any: Any? = null

        try {
            // Operation on "any"
        }finally {
            return any as? T
        }
    }
```

And I'm calling a generic function as `get<List<Article?>>(key))` in which case IDE doesn't "complain" about it. Then I'm making List nullable as `get<List<Article?>?>(key))` in this case IDE shows following warning for `<List<Article?>?>` part.

Warning message:

> Remove explicit type arguments

This warning message is not shown when called as `get<Article?>(key))` or `get<Article>(key))`. Now, I wonder

**1)** if it's because the generic type is `T?` but not `List<T?>?` or some other factor is causing this warning?

**2)** if there is a way to return `List<CustomObject>` or `Object` from generic function when relevant type parameter is supplied when calling a generic function?

Comment: I don't see any warnings in AS 3.5

Comment: @AndreiTanana Yeah, you're right. I was calling this method from a function with this `Single<List<Article?>?>` return type and it was automatically assigning type parameter. `getArticles(key): Single<List<Article?>?>{get<List<Article?>?>(key))}`. Since return type parameter of `getArticles` is `List<Article?>?` this parameter is automatically inherited by function inside a body that requires type parameter. That's why AS was calling it explicit type argument.